# QImage is null while reading image from resources

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qimage, qtgui

I am developing a simple fps shooter for a college project. I am using C++, Qt and OpenGL and I'm having a problem during texture loading. I put my textures into resource file. After loading, QImage object which stores a texture, is null.
Here is my resource file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/sounds">
        <file alias="rifle">rifle.wav</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/textures">
        <file alias="ground">ground00.tga</file>
        <file alias="sky_back">sky_back.tga</file>
        <file alias="sky_front">sky_front.tga</file>
        <file alias="sky_left">sky_left.tga</file>
        <file alias="sky_right">sky_right.tga</file>
        <file alias="sky_up">sky_up.tga</file>
        <file alias="wall05">wall05.tga</file>
        <file alias="wall06">wall06.tga</file>
        <file alias="wall07">wall07.tga</file>
        <file alias="wall08">wall08.tga</file>
        <file alias="wall09">wall09.tga</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Function which loads texture:

```
void GLWidget::load_texture(const QString  & file, GLuint texHandle)
{
   //load image
   QImage tex(file);
   if(tex.isNull())
   {
       std::cerr<<"File "<<file.toStdString()<<" not found"<<std::endl;
       return;
   }

   tex = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(tex);
   int w = tex.width();
   int h = tex.height();

   //generate the texture
   glGenTextures(1,&texture[texHandle]);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[texHandle]);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,w,h,0,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,(GLvoid*)tex.bits());
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to call this function it prints "File ... not found" and returns.
I tried to call this function:

```
load_texture(":/textures/ground00.tga",0);//using filename
load_texture(":/textures/ground",0);//using alias
```

however, both calls fail. QImageReader supports tga files, "tga" is in output of

```
qDebug() << QImageReader::supportedImageFormats ();
```

edit:
I have added following lines on top the `load_texture` function

```
if(QFile::exists(file))
{
    std::cout<<"File "<<file.toStdString()<<" exists"<<std::endl;
}
```

and for case when i am using resource alias `load_texture(":/textures/ground",0);` it returns true

Comment: I'm stating the obvious here... but if QImage isNull() returns true, it must indicate that ":/textures/ground00.tga" is not a valid path to the object or that the resource is not valid.

Comment: Are you having the tga image format plugin installed? Can you check that regardless the supportedImageFormats() call?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: how can i check it?

Comment: /usr/lib/qt/plugins/imageformats/ on my Archlinux. The tga plugin is coming from the qtimageformats module.

Comment: @LaszloPapp i am using windows

Comment: Check your Qt installation. Look for a plugins folder. If there is none, you will need to explicitly load the plugins with QLibrary. Have you done that?

Comment: I have files qtga.dll and qtgad.dll in plugins\imageformats folder

Comment: Even with the qtga libraries in my plugin directory, I was still unable to load an uncompressed RLE TGA file created with GIMP.

Comment: @piwowarek102: ok, good, is it for the same version of Qt that you have? They have to match. Just to see if we are on the same page: if you do not use resource for this, but filesytem path, then the tga loading works fine?

Comment: @LaszloPapp i have only one version of Qt (5.2.0), when i use filesystem path i have the same problem

Comment: As asked before, does it work from filesystem rather than resource?

Comment: I would suggest you do not re-assign `tex` using the returned result of this function. In the event that no data conversion is necessary it is possible that invoking the destructor of the original `tex` object to perform the re-assignment is leading to this behavior. I do not know how `QImage` is implemented so this is only speculation, but it is a bad idea anyway. Try constructing another `QImage` object to store the result instead.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: actually, that is the right way to do in Qt.

Comment: Really? That seems kind of ridiculous, why does it take a const reference then? Might as well have it modify the original object and return void.

Comment: @LaszloPapp It does not work from filesystem, I converted files to jpg and it works now.

Comment: @piwowarek102: can you give a quick trial to QImageLoader from the filesystem with absolute path? Does that fail too?